# Python conditional variable assignment using comparison operators

Tags: python, django

I was going through the django rest frame work tutorial here

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

In the tutorial there is a line where the author does the following assignment.

```
    linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False
    options = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}
```

I've never seen this form of conditional assignment...i'm not even sure it is.
I was under the impression the only way to do conditional formatting in python was

var = something if  else something_else

So what exactly will linenos and options return?

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is taking advantage of how logical operators work in python. The statements are interpreted from left to right, and the last expression to be evaluated provides the result. The `and` and `or` operators also "short-circuit", which means they only evaluate their second arguments if the first one is false.

These features can be exploited to create a ternary operator (which Python didn't have before version 2.5 - see [PEP 308 -- Conditional Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)). So the two lines of code in the question are equivalent to:

```
    linenos = 'table' if self.lineno else False
    options = {'title': self.title} if self.title else {}
```